# Raw query to set AutoIncrement to false?

Tags: laravel, database, postgresql, migration, laravel-8

The `id` column in the `student` table is an auto incrementing one.I wanted to make that to non - autoincrementing. May i know, how can i modify the below query to work as such?

```
 DB::statement("ALTER TABLE student SET AUTO_INCREMENT=FALSE;");
```

the above code shows the below error.

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException

  SQLSTATE[42601]: Syntax error: 7 ERROR:  syntax error at or near "AUTO_INCREMENT"
LINE 1: ALTER TABLE student SET AUTO_INCREMENT=FALSE;
                                ^ (SQL: ALTER TABLE student SET AUTO_INCREMENT=FALSE;)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct syntax in PostgreSQL would be:

```
ALTER TABLE student ALTER COLUMN id DROP DEFAULT;
```

Where `id` is the serial column.

You might also want to drop the `not null` constraint :

```
ALTER TABLE student ALTER COLUMN id DROP NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of why posting table definitions (ddl) and Postgres version can be critical. @Zakaria is correct if the Postgres version is prior to version 10, or if version 10 or later and is still defined as serial/bigserial. However the preferred definition for version 10 and later  is `generated always as identity`. If defined as identity you need:

```
alter table student alter column id drop identity.
```

I would not drop a `not null` constraint, and if it is the PK it is moot point as it will automatically be not null.